# Slowness when using the Windows port of the VMware Fusion product

Tags: mac, vmware-fusion

Since I have installed the VMware Fusion product 2.0.6 my MAC side works well, but my Windows is slow at best, accessing, printing, etc.

I have gone in and changed my Virtual machine to dual processors, adding more memory for the application (noting I have a MacBook Pro - 64 gig of ram...etc.

Not a slow machine...I have emailed VMware for suggestions other then upgrading to 3.0 which may be the known issue but suggestions, tips from anyone that has run into the same issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a note to say that enabling two virtual processors won't necessarily increase the speed of your VM, as in some cases it may have to wait until both physical cores are free to grab context on the machine.

Comment: Also curious as to how you got your hands on 32GB SO-DIMMs.

Comment: Your Question is misleading - you seem to be saying that a Windows VM is slow running under Fusion. In any case there is no such thing as a "Windows port" of Fusion, there is a similar product called VMware Workstation but if you are running V2 of that you really do need to upgrade. @phoebus - nice one, I want me some of those.

Comment: And while I'm at it, what version of Windows is installed in the VM, what's the actual config of your MacPro and the VM config (Configured RAM, CPU's, type of disk) and what's it running (anything heavy duty like SQL for example).

Answer (score 0):

It's just plain slow as a solution as far as I can tell. I've run various virtual machines on VMFusion and it's generally troublesome with Linux as well. If you want a machine that can run more than a browser you should consider dual boot with Boot Camp. It's really miles better.